# how to exchange position of array terms use numpy in python?

Tags: numpy

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)

[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]
 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]]
```

how to exchange position of [4 5] and [10 11] use numpy? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those rows can be sliced with:

```
In [1418]: a[:,2,:]
Out[1418]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [10, 11]])
```

viewed in reverse order with:

```
In [1419]: a[::-1,2,:]
Out[1419]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [ 4,  5]])
```

and replaced with:

```
In [1420]: a[:,2,:] = a[::-1,2,:]
In [1421]: a
Out[1421]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [10, 11]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [ 4,  5]]])
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot